# Can private IP addresses be set up recursively?

Tags: ip-address

We can assign one public IP address to a network, and within the network, distribute the private IP addresses which can come from one of the three reserved ranges:

- 10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255/8 (16,777,216 hosts)
- 172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255/12 (1,048,576 hosts)
- 192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255/16 (65,536 hosts)

Is it correct that in the network, we can assign one private IP address (e.g. 192.168.0.10) to a "subnetwork", and  within that "subnetwork", we can distribute private IP addresses  in range 192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255 to the hosts in the "subnetwork", and 192.168.0.10 in the "subnetwork" and 192.168.0.10 in the original network can coexist and refer to different things?

Thanks.

Comment: They are different.

Comment: The second part of [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains subnetting, but you must be familiar with the first part before getting to subnetting.

Comment: Also, look at [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/49977/8499).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  IP addresses are unique. If you’re using private addresses, they will be unique within your organization.

Comment: Inside your organization, if there is a router, can the hosts under that router reuse the privates IP addresses in your organization? I think yes.

Comment: Absolutely not. Think of addresses like telephone numbers. You can’t have two people with the same number.

Comment: isn't  it that a router create a new scope for reusing private IP addresses?

Comment: No. A router forwards packets from one network to another. If two devices have the same address you won’t be able to tell them apart. A host with the address 192.168.2.3 is the same host regardless of the subnet mask.

Comment: "A router forwards packets from one network to another. "  At your home, when you uses a router and modem to connect to your ISP, does the router create a new network inside your home? When you use a second router to connect to the router, does the second router create a new network, in which you can reuse all the private IP addresses again, in the sense that they overlap with those IP addresses assigned by the first router?

Comment: No, you can't reuse them.   BTW, home networking questions should be asked on [su].